# "Job failed to start" - Hey but why?

Tags: ubuntu, service, init.d, daemon

I'm running through an error that's giving me serious headache. Tried to Google for it but all I find is about MySQL which doesn't apply here.

I've just updated Node and Ghost (blogging platform) on Ubuntu. Had some major issues to update Node since it didn't come installed in a normal way so apt-get didn't work. I was able to install Node with `NVM`. After trying to restart the service it now says "Job failed to start"

They're using this `init.d` script: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/TryGhost/Ghost-Config/master/init.d/ghost which I've updated to be like this:

```
PATH=/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin
DESC="Ghost"
NAME=ghost
GHOST_ROOT=/var/www/ghost
GHOST_GROUP=ghost
GHOST_USER=ghost
DAEMON=/root/.nvm/versions/node/v4.2.3/bin/node
DAEMON_ARGS="$GHOST_ROOT/index.js"
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
SCRIPTNAME=/etc/init.d/$NAME
export NODE_ENV=production
```

Other than that, it remains the same.

However, I can't work out the "Job Failed to start" part, is not giving any other message even though `VERBOSE` seems to be set to `yes`.

I've checked permissions on new bins and all seems alright. Also tried to run the blog manually and it seems to work without any errors.

How can I debug the reason of the failure?

Comment: Which ubuntu version you are using? 14.04 and previous uses upstart with sysvinit compatible but higher uses systemd. So you need rewrite your service description with upstart or systemd.

Comment: @risyasin I'm on 14.04.3 if I recall right. Can you point me to how to do that briefly? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Managed to fix this. Will write an answer to explain the process.

Comment: @AntonioLaguna Mind sharing that info now...?